# Saving results of loop iterations in a game

Tags: python

I am trying to make a hangman game and I am running into trouble with the display. I have a loop that is supposed to put the correctly guessed letters in the right places, however it only shows the correct location for one letter at a time. I thought it would be helpful to save the result of the previous iteration, and then display that, but I am not sure how to do that.

```
import random,time
hanglist = []
answerlist = []
file_var = open("wordlist.100000")
for n in file_var:
    hanglist.append(file_var.readline())
word = random.choice(hanglist)
print("word is",word)
guesses = 10
while guesses != 0:
    print("guess a letter")
    answer = input()
    answerlist.append(answer)
    if answer in word:
        m = list(word)
        for n in m:
            if n == answer:
                print(answer, end = '')
            else:
                print('_', end = '')                
    else:
        print("close, but not exactly")
    guesses -= 1
```

And here are the outputs

```
word is fabric

guess a letter
f
f______guess a letter
a
_a_____guess a letter
```

Comment: what is the expected output and also u want to save only previous state or all previous states?

Comment: Please properly indent your code

Comment: `if n in answerlist: print(n, end='')`

Comment: @VenkataGogu all previous states

Comment: do you need to break out of loop when the correct guesses of all letters are made ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your issue just replace `if n==answer` to `if n in answer`. But, from the above code, I can see code can't handle these issues:

1. If the user guesses the same word again and again
2. After 4 guesses are done and total word is guessed, then code should break out of the loop, which it is not happening.
3. While reading line, it need to strip the '\n' otherwise its really hard

My code addresses these issue:

```
import random,time
hanglist = []
answerlist = []
file_var = open("wordlist.100000")
for n in file_var:
    # strips the '/n' at the end
    hanglist.append(file_var.readline().rstrip())
word = random.choice(hanglist)
print("word is",word)
guesses = 10
while guesses!=0:
    print("guess a letter")
    answer = input()
    if answer in answerlist:
        continue
    answerlist.append(answer)
    if answer in word:
        # to print entire word guessed till now- with current and previous iterations
        word_print = ''
        for n in word:
            # to print all the last state occurences
            if n in answerlist: 
                word_print += n
            else:
                word_print += '_'
        print(word_print,end='')
        # word is correctly guessed
        if '_' not in word_print: 
            break
    else:
        print("close, but not exactly")
    guesses = guesses-1
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value... in particular you fix, but don't mention, the core issue.

Comment: It's already mentioned in other answers and not sure its worth to repeat the same thing. Instead, I extended other answer. I'll keep in mind. From next time, I'll try to keep as verbose as possible

Comment: @VenkataGogu What is the purpose of the word_print variable?

Comment: @AthreyaDaniel, it accumulates all the previous states and print the current state

Comment: @VenkataGogu just a clarification: what do you mean by state?

Comment: My bad! state refers to iteration. sorry for the confusion. Usually in games, I refer to state. I apologize for confusion

Comment: @VenkataGogu Sorry! I didn't know you could only accept one answer at a time

Comment: @VenkataGogu Yours was definitely the most helpful, thank you

Answer (score -1):

Your issue is with

```
if n == answer:
    print(answer,end = '')
else:
    print('_', end = '')
```

which only compares each letter with the current guess, `answer`. Instead, if you use

```
if n in answerlist:
    print(n, end = '')
else:
    print('_', end = '')
```

it will show the letter if that letter is in the list of their previous guesses.

Additionally: the previous `m= list(word)` is not necessary, as `for n in word:` is valid.

Comment: when I make this change i am left with this output:

Comment: e
e_e__________e_e__guess a letter

Comment: it replaces the first letter already guessed with the letter it is checking for

Comment: you missed the 2nd part of the change, you should print `n`, the letter we're checking, not `answer`, the letter they guessed.